# How do I find all the exe files and tar.gz them in seperate archives?

Tags: bash

I need to be able to use commands like find.

Something similar to this. But archive each exe file in its own tar.gz archive. So for example win.exe will become win.tar.gz and file.exe will become file.tar.gz.

find folder_name -name "*.exe" -type f -print -exec tar -zcvf temp.tar.gz '{}' \;

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
find folder_name -name "*.exe" -type f|while read file; do 
    tar -zcvf $(basename $file).tar.gz $file; 
done
```

left taking out the .exe from the archive name as an exercise ;).

Answer (score 0):

```
for file in *.exe
do
    tar -zcvf ${file/.exe}.tar.gz $file
done
```

Or on one line:

```
for file *.exe; do tar -zcvf ${file/.exe}.tar.gz $file; done
```

Replace `*.exe` with `folder_name/*.exe` to search in a specific folder.

Comment: The problem is that your are not recursive in the folder, but it may be sufficient depending on emcgfx's need.

Answer (score 0):

Compilation of two :

```
find folder_name -name "*.exe" -type f|while read file; do
    localfile=$(basename $file); tar -zcvf ${localfile/%exe/tar\.gz} $file;
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
find folder_name -name "*.exe" -type f -exec sh -c 'tar -zcvf "$(basename {} .exe).tar.gz" "{}"' \;
```

No need for `for` or `while`.